# How can I get a return value while hooking in android(using xposed)?

Tags: android, hook

For example, there is a method like

```
private byte[] example() {
    byte[] parameter = 0x0; 
    /*modify the parameter*/
    return parameter;
}
```

How could I get the value of parameter?

Comment: just call `example()`

Comment: @Boss But every time you call it the value of parameter will change.

Comment: Please explain your requirement little more clearly..

Comment: @Boss Oh, thanks. Recently I am playing with xposed, which is used to android hooking (maybe you have already known what I am talking about). I want to get the value of parameter after the method called by app, and I think every time the method is called, the value of parameter is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the the return value is very simple just hook the method like you would normally then call the method "getResult" of the MethodHookParam class.

When ever the hooked method is called again the variable "theReturnVal" is going to hold the new return value.

```
findAndHookMethod("example", classLoader, "exmpleMethod", new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {

            byte[] theReturnVal= (byte[]) param.getResult();

        }
});
```

You can take a look at my open source xposed module for a more complete example.
https://github.com/Programming4life/SnapColors/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/manvir/SnapColors/App.java#L428